# modify linkgeneration: use subdomain for namespaces in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to modify the link generation in mediawiki to use a subdomain for namespaces.

For example: *extra.wiki-domain.tld/123* instead of *wiki-domain.tld/extra:123*

the given domain to wiki should be possible be mod_rewrite, but how i modify the link generation inside the mediawiki to generate the links this way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd) hook.